# Xtify Missing api key

Tags: push, api-key, xtify

I'm trying to send a push from a php server with the example code from https://github.com/xtifyTools/xtifyTools/tree/master/PHPScripts

I put in "ADD_YOUR_APIKEY_HERE" the Google API key and "ADD_YOUR_APPKEY_HERE" the application key from xtify, the message is:

{"apiKey":"AIza....","appKey":"71....","sendAll":true,"content":{"subject":"prueba desde servidor","message":"mensaje, mensaje!!","action":{"type":"DEFAULT","data":"","label":""}}}

But I receive the error Missing API Key.
Where is the problem?

I send push from the xtify console and I receive it, but the devices don't appear in the Test Implementation although the application is development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the API Key fragment you have in your example is not correct.  When using the class, make sure that you set the API Key that you've created in the xtify console: https://console.xtify.com/api-keys-manager